# How do I connect web API to a react project through AJAX?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have two projects within a solution file, one of which is a react project and the other webAPI project. I verified that the webAPI works by accessing the controller through the URL. My only problem now is accessing the webAPI project from the React project.I know that both have to be running in separate instances in order for this to work, I am just not sure what to put in my AJAX code to call the webAPI.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `axios` library, which is great to use on ReactJs applications.
Here it is the official npm libary whre you can also look at its documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

You can make requests as simple as this:

```
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

// Optionally the request above could also be done as
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

You can look at its documentation on how to make `post`, `delete` and other requests and use configurations if you need.

Comment: This is a great solution. My only problem now is keeping the webAPI project running long enough to access the controller.

Comment: @Paradigm if you're on `Visual Studio` just press `CTRL + F5` or go to menu on the top and then `Debug > Start Without Debugging`, and you can run it locally

Comment: Oh that is what I have been doing, but the webAPI project does not have a landing page per say so i have to access each controller when i run it

Comment: @Paradigm of course it does not have any landing page, since its only an API. Try to run it with `CTRL + F5` and it will open a tab in your browser, ex: `localhost:55215/api/values`, and if you have still `ValuesController` (that comes by default as a template when you create an API), it will show `[ "value1", "value2" ]` in the browser. And then you can access it any controller by `localhost:port/api/[controller]/(action)`

Answer (score 0):

This article will really help you https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html to implement ajax in react.

You can use browser's Fetch API that will help to access resources from other networks in your case from web API. refer- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

In your react app, you can write something like-

```
fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result)
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
```

Comment: I am actually using this approach, my only issue now is having the webAPI stay open long enough to get a response. This side project does not have a front end to keep it running long enough.

Comment: You mean to say you do not want to keep open api project?

Comment: I need it since it is the only way to access the controller using react. I am just not sure how to keep it running long enough to access the controller. When I run it, it downloads a json file with the result then closes.

Comment: You can host you API solution in IIS this will solve you problem